# How to compare component versions for sending notifications?

Tags: notifications, workflow, tridion, tridion2009

I am working with Workflows (Automatic Activities).
I would like to show which parts of the component have been modified via e-mail.
I guess I can use something like: 
my_server/views/ASP/CompareFrameset.asp?SystemIdentifier=tcm:25-18409

But I don't know how to use the attribute "SystemIdentifier".

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you try to build the next link:

```
http://<yourServer>/Views/ASP/CompareFrameset.asp?tds51cmwknlcom&URI=Compare&CONTEXTURI=tcm:25-24905&FILTER=auto&ITEMTYPE=&MODE=
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want to include a link to the comparing functionality: The System identifier is the URI of the Component currently in Workflow.

Comment: Thank you, I have already try with the component. But didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works in a similar way with Tridion 2009 - check the documentation for "[Comparing Activities](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_54_2DDAFF2CF95E4430AA0F27AD7A91B5F8)" in Tridion 2011 SP1. In short: you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I have checked the documentation. But, I think is not what I am looking for. First of all, I am in the first activity, so I can not compare with anything. When the first activity has been finished starts a automatic activity to send an email to the reviewer person. In this email, I want to include a link for comparing the changes, and then the reviewer can or not accept the task. I have seen in Tridion that when I compare a component versions calls this asp: ASP/CompareFrameset.asp.   So, I am trying to guess how to used it.

Comment: I am trying to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the System Identifier is a unique ID used in the MDVC to distinguish between open CME sessions.

It combines information such as the User ID, the version of the Content Manager, and the server name. You can read the current System Idenfifier from the SystemIdentifier property of the MDVC.